# R: merge 2 data frames, one of them with repeated measures, keeping NAs where appropriate

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Say I have 2 data frames I want to `merge`. `df1` has repeated measures per sample (which I do not actually know how many, and can be different per each sample), while `df2` only has one measure for the same samples.

As a MWE, something like this:

```
> df1=data.frame(letter=rep(LETTERS[1:5],each=3), val1=1:15)
> df2=data.frame(letter=LETTERS[1:5], val2=16:20)
> df1
   letter val1
1       A    1
2       A    2
3       A    3
4       B    4
5       B    5
6       B    6
7       C    7
8       C    8
9       C    9
10      D   10
11      D   11
12      D   12
13      E   13
14      E   14
15      E   15
> df2
  letter val2
1      A   16
2      B   17
3      C   18
4      D   19
5      E   20
```

I want to `merge` them in such a way that this is reflected. As of now I can do:

```
> merge(df1, df2)
   letter val1 val2
1       A    1   16
2       A    2   16
3       A    3   16
4       B    4   17
5       B    5   17
6       B    6   17
7       C    7   18
8       C    8   18
9       C    9   18
10      D   10   19
11      D   11   19
12      D   12   19
13      E   13   20
14      E   14   20
15      E   15   20
```

But ideally, I would need this:

```
> merge(df1, df2, all=T)
   letter rep val1 val2
1       A   1    1   16
2       A   2    2   NA
3       A   3    3   NA
4       B   1    4   17
5       B   2    5   NA
6       B   3    6   NA
7       C   1    7   18
8       C   2    8   NA
9       C   3    9   NA
10      D   1   10   19
11      D   2   11   NA
12      D   3   12   NA
13      E   1   13   20
14      E   2   14   NA
15      E   3   15   NA
```

But I do not have that `rep` column since the beginning, so I should add it post hoc, but I do not know how... Alternatively, maybe `merge` has some option to only list the first match for the `val2` column...

Any help? It should be easy but I am getting into loops and checks to add that `rep` columns, and that is probably not the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can join the two datasets together and create a `rep` column which is row number for each `letter` and turn `val2` to `NA` except 1st row.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'letter') %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(rep = row_number(), 
         val2 = replace(val2, -1, NA))

#  letter  val1  val2   rep
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A          1    16     1
# 2 A          2    NA     2
# 3 A          3    NA     3
# 4 B          4    17     1
# 5 B          5    NA     2
# 6 B          6    NA     3
# 7 C          7    18     1
# 8 C          8    NA     2
# 9 C          9    NA     3
#10 D         10    19     1
#11 D         11    NA     2
#12 D         12    NA     3
#13 E         13    20     1
#14 E         14    NA     2
#15 E         15    NA     3
```

To replace multiple such `val` columns without explicitly mentioning them one by one we can use `across` :

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'letter') %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(rep = row_number(), 
         across(val2:valn, ~replace(., -1, NA)))
```

---

In base R :

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
cols <- c('val2')
df3[duplicated(df3[c('letter', cols)]), cols] <- NA
```

Comment: Hhmm but what I actually need is the `NAs` inserted appropriately to reflect that `val2` doesnt have repeated measures (only 1 value taken in the same day as rep 1 from `val1`)... I actually don't need the `rep` column, only as a means to achieve that

Comment: Also, consider my actual data frames do not have just `val1` and `val2`, but tens (maybe over 100) value columns with different names

Comment: I corrected the answer to get `NA`'s in `val2`. For the 2nd comment do you mean you don't want to do replace column individually? See if my edit answers that. You can remove `rep = row_number()` from the answer if you don't need the `rep` column.

Comment: Getting there, the problem is that the value column names can have any name, not just val1:n

Comment: In `across` you can use pattern of column names `starts_with('val')`,`ends_with('val')`, `contains('val')`. Or you can use column numbers `2:20` or `c(2:5, 8:11)` and if there is no way you can create groups of column that you want to apply this function to you need to specify them manually.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish the same with base functions? or trying to avoid the %>% cause this goes into a package I have and I always have problems with that

Comment: How do you define columns that you want to apply this to? Is it by pattern in column names or column numbers (what are they) ?

Comment: I have a feeling it would be easier to do the `merge` as I do, and then just identify rows where `val2` and `letter` are identical through `duplicated`, and introduce NAs using those indexes

Comment: I have updated the answer. Maybe that is what you are looking for. Can you check @DaniCee

Comment: I think the `duplicated` answer is perfect for my actual data! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base version that only needs to know columns to *not* replace with NAs.

```r
merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = "letter")
do_not_clean <- "letter"
nms <- setdiff(names(merged), do_not_clean)
spl <- by(merged, merged$letter, function(y) {
  y[nms] <- lapply(y[nms], function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))
  y$rep <- seq_len(nrow(y))
  y
})
out <- do.call(rbind, spl)
out
#      letter val1 val2 rep
# A.1       A    1   16   1
# A.2       A    2   NA   2
# A.3       A    3   NA   3
# B.4       B    4   17   1
# B.5       B    5   NA   2
# B.6       B    6   NA   3
# C.7       C    7   18   1
# C.8       C    8   NA   2
# C.9       C    9   NA   3
# D.10      D   10   19   1
# D.11      D   11   NA   2
# D.12      D   12   NA   3
# E.13      E   13   20   1
# E.14      E   14   NA   2
# E.15      E   15   NA   3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `merge` function to merge them:

```
library(dplyr)


df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "letter", all = T) %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(rep = row_number(),
         val2 = replace(val2, -1, NA))


df3
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   letter [5]
   letter  val1  val2   rep
   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
 1 A          1    16     1
 2 A          2    NA     2
 3 A          3    NA     3
 4 B          4    17     1
 5 B          5    NA     2
 6 B          6    NA     3
 7 C          7    18     1
 8 C          8    NA     2
 9 C          9    NA     3
10 D         10    19     1
11 D         11    NA     2
12 D         12    NA     3
13 E         13    20     1
14 E         14    NA     2
15 E         15    NA     3
```